# automate creating subsets of data

Tags: r

I am looking to subset a large amount of data to make it easier to handle and plot. I hope to create groups about 10 variables long so my graphs do not become over-encumbered. I made some dummy data from 'mpg' to demonstrate my plan.

```
library(tidyverse)

##Creates a list of car manufacturers and how many models they offer

car_types <- as.data.frame(table(mpg$manufacturer))

##filters to only having manufacturers offering at least 10 models

most_models <-filter(car_types, Freq >= 10)

##subset mpg data to only manufacturers who have 10 models

mpg_mm <- filter(mpg,mpg$manufacturer %in% most_models$Var1)

#returns mpg, three at a time and only for manufacturers offering 10 models

set_1 <- filter(mpg_mm, mpg_mm$manufacturer %in% most_models[1:3,]$Var1)
set_2 <- filter(mpg_mm, mpg_mm$manufacturer %in% most_models[4:6,]$Var1)
```

#What is the method for creating set_3, set_4,..., etc.? I am looking to subset the my data to make many graphs with a reasonable number of geoms/graph. Can I use a data frame like this to help automatically create set_3, set_4?

```
a <- data.frame(word= 'set',
                 set= c(1:151),
                 start= c(1,1+(1:150)*3),
                 end= c(3,3+( 1:150)*3)
                )  
df <- unite(a, set_name, c(word, set), remove=TRUE)

#this works
set_3<- filter(mpg_mm, mpg_mm$manufacturer %in% most_models[df$start[3]:df$end[3],]$Var1)

#but creating an object name does not
        
df$set_name[3]<- filter(mpg_mm, 
                         mpg_mm$manufacturer %in% 
                           most_models[df$start[3]:df$end[3],]$Var1)
```

#In the end I want to do this for all 150+ sets

Comment: You haven't accepted any of the answer, didn't these serve your purpose? Please tell.  Acceptance and upcoming the answers is one the best practices on SO for future references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is base R approach :

```
inds <- seq(nrow(most_models))
result <- by(inds, ceiling(inds/3), function(x) 
             subset(mpg_mm, manufacturer %in% most_models$Var1[x]))
```

We divide the `most_models` datasets into 3 rows each and select rows from `mpg_mm` where any of those models are present.

Answer (score 1):

We loop over the corresponding elements of 'start', 'end' columns of 'df' with `map2` (from `purrr`) into a `list` , `filter` the 'mpg_mm' rows based on the sequence of index from 'start', 'end' (`.x:.y`) to extract the 'Var1' from 'most_models' and check if it is `%in%` 'manufacturer' and remove the `list` elements that have 0 rows with `keep` (or `discard`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out_lst <- map2(df$start, df$end, ~
     mpg_mm %>%
        filter(manufacturer %in% most_models$Var1[.x:.y])) %>%
      keep(~ nrow(.x) > 0)
```

NOTE: If we need a single dataset, use `map2_dfr`

Answer (score 1):

Simply this strategy will also work-

**1** Create a `dense_rank` on the field on which the subsets are to be created.

**2** `group_split` after breaking the `dense_rank` into `integer division` i.e. `%/%` by desired number (say 3)

**No need to create a data frame with start and end fields**

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>% filter(n() >=10) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(dummy = dense_rank(manufacturer) %/% 3) %>% group_split(dummy)
```

## Output

```
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    manufacturer: character
    model       : character
    displ       : double
    year        : integer
    cyl         : integer
    trans       : character
    drv         : character
    cty         : integer
    hwy         : integer
    fl          : character
    class       : character
    dummy       : double
  >
>[4]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 37 x 12
   manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class   dummy
   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact     0
 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact     0
 3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact     0
 4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact     0
 5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact     0
 6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact     0
 7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact     0
 8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact     0
 9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact     0
10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact     0
# ... with 27 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 76 x 12
   manufacturer model       displ  year   cyl trans    drv     cty   hwy fl    class   dummy
   <chr>        <chr>       <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>    <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 dodge        caravan 2wd   2.4  1999     4 auto(l3) f        18    24 r     minivan     1
 2 dodge        caravan 2wd   3    1999     6 auto(l4) f        17    24 r     minivan     1
 3 dodge        caravan 2wd   3.3  1999     6 auto(l4) f        16    22 r     minivan     1
 4 dodge        caravan 2wd   3.3  1999     6 auto(l4) f        16    22 r     minivan     1
 5 dodge        caravan 2wd   3.3  2008     6 auto(l4) f        17    24 r     minivan     1
 6 dodge        caravan 2wd   3.3  2008     6 auto(l4) f        17    24 r     minivan     1
 7 dodge        caravan 2wd   3.3  2008     6 auto(l4) f        11    17 e     minivan     1
 8 dodge        caravan 2wd   3.8  1999     6 auto(l4) f        15    22 r     minivan     1
 9 dodge        caravan 2wd   3.8  1999     6 auto(l4) f        15    21 r     minivan     1
10 dodge        caravan 2wd   3.8  2008     6 auto(l6) f        16    23 r     minivan     1
# ... with 66 more rows

[[3]]
# A tibble: 61 x 12
   manufacturer model          displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class   dummy
   <chr>        <chr>          <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 nissan       altima           2.4  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 r     compact     2
 2 nissan       altima           2.4  1999     4 auto(l4)   f        19    27 r     compact     2
 3 nissan       altima           2.5  2008     4 auto(av)   f        23    31 r     midsize     2
 4 nissan       altima           2.5  2008     4 manual(m6) f        23    32 r     midsize     2
 5 nissan       altima           3.5  2008     6 manual(m6) f        19    27 p     midsize     2
 6 nissan       altima           3.5  2008     6 auto(av)   f        19    26 p     midsize     2
 7 nissan       maxima           3    1999     6 auto(l4)   f        18    26 r     midsize     2
 8 nissan       maxima           3    1999     6 manual(m5) f        19    25 r     midsize     2
 9 nissan       maxima           3.5  2008     6 auto(av)   f        19    25 p     midsize     2
10 nissan       pathfinder 4wd   3.3  1999     6 auto(l4)   4        14    17 r     suv         2
# ... with 51 more rows

[[4]]
# A tibble: 27 x 12
   manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class   dummy
   <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 volkswagen   gti     2    1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 r     compact     3
 2 volkswagen   gti     2    1999     4 auto(l4)   f        19    26 r     compact     3
 3 volkswagen   gti     2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        21    29 p     compact     3
 4 volkswagen   gti     2    2008     4 auto(s6)   f        22    29 p     compact     3
 5 volkswagen   gti     2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        17    24 r     compact     3
 6 volkswagen   jetta   1.9  1999     4 manual(m5) f        33    44 d     compact     3
 7 volkswagen   jetta   2    1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 r     compact     3
 8 volkswagen   jetta   2    1999     4 auto(l4)   f        19    26 r     compact     3
 9 volkswagen   jetta   2    2008     4 auto(s6)   f        22    29 p     compact     3
10 volkswagen   jetta   2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        21    29 p     compact     3
# ... with 17 more rows
```

**Output will be a list of four data-frames**

**Note-2** If you'll add `1` to `dummy` the field can serve the dual purpose of `sub_set number`.

## For saving list items as individual subsets (objects)

```
dd <- mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>% filter(n() >=10) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(dummy = dense_rank(manufacturer) %/% 3) %>% group_split(dummy)

names(dd) <- paste("set", 1:length(dd), sep = "_")

list2env(dd, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Good luck